# &039 instead of apostrophe and &amp instead of & in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, meta-tags, substitution

I'm using drupal 7 to build a website, and when I see the source code of my pages, the apostrophes are substituted by &039 and & by &amp. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally correct, the ampersand and apostrophe symbols (along with many others) are reserved characters in HTML and cannot be used directly in the code without first being 'escaped'. The [W3C page on HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) explains it in very good detail.

Don't worry, Google is smart enough to know this and when it 'reads' your text it will substitute the correct symbols in; your text will show correctly in search engine results :)

Comment: I have a similar issue with service links module for twitter?

Answer (score 0):

Place your cursor in the position where you want the apostrophe. Hold down 'alt' key, type 0180, then release the 'alt key'.

Comment: should be mentioned that this only works on Windows, I guess.